# Player 1 switches to Player 2. How do I switch back from Player 2 to Player 1? It's a 2 player number guessing game

Tags: python

I'm writing a Python code for a 2 player number guessing game. Player 1 tries to guess, and if they get it wrong, the program should move on to Player 2. If Player 2 guesses wrong, the program should return to Player 1. I'm using an 'active, passive' code that I found here on stack overflow, and it works when going from Player 1 to Player 2, but I can't go back to Player 1 if Player 2 guesses incorrectly.

If they actually get it right the code won't say the programmed sentence either. It just moves on to Player 2, or prints nothing.

```
import random
answer= random.randint(1,100)
print('The bingo answer is', answer, '.', 'This will not be shown to the user.')

upperLimit=100
lowerLimit=1
guessingPlayer= ""

active, passive = "1", "2"
while guessingPlayer== "1":
    print('~ ', lowerLimit, 'to ',upperLimit, '~')
    guess = input('Player 1:')
    if int(guess) == answer:
      print("Bingo! Player 1 wins!")
      break
  
else:
    guess= input('Player 1:')
    if int(guess) < answer:
      print('Wrong!')
      lowerLimit=guess
      print('~', lowerLimit, 'to', upperLimit, '~')
    if int(guess)>answer:
      print('Wrong!')
      upperLimit=guess
      print('~', lowerLimit, 'to', upperLimit, '~')
      passive, active= "1", "2"

while guessingPlayer== "2":
  guess = input('Player 2:')
  if int(guess) ==answer:
    print("Bingo! Player 2 wins!")
    break

else:
  guess= input('Player 2:')
  if int(guess)<answer:
    print('Wrong!')
    lowerLimit=guess
    print('~', lowerLimit, 'to', upperLimit, '~')
  if int(guess)>answer:
    print('Wrong!')
    upperLimit=guess
    print('~', lowerLimit, 'to', upperLimit, '~')
    active, passive= "1", "2"
```

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]. Write some new code which just focuses on the problem at hand, nothing to do with players, guesses, printing, nothing.

Comment: "but I can't go back to Player 1 if Player 2 guesses incorrectly." Why not? Did you try anything at all to solve  the problem? Think: when should the player change? How do you know who the player should be after the change? It seems like what you're saying is that `if` it's currently player 1, it should become player 2, and otherwise (i.e. `else`), it should become player 1. Can you think of a way to translate that into code? I don't understand how there's an actual question here, since you apparently already know how to use `if` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function, which will simplify your code a lot.

As a remark, in Python variable naming convention is not camel case (`myVariable`) but using underscores (`my_variable`).

```
import random

answer = random.randint(1, 100)
print('The bingo answer is', answer, '.', 'This will not be shown to the user.')


def ask_player(player_number, lower_bound_, upper_bound_):
    """ asks the player, returns True if the guess is correct, False o.w. """
    print('~ ', lower_bound_, 'to ', upper_bound_, '~')
    current_guess = input('Player %s:' % player_number)
    if int(current_guess) == answer:
        print("Bingo! Player %s wins!" % player_number)
        return True
    return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    upper_limit = 100
    lower_limit = 1
    guessing_player = ""

    active, passive = "2", "1"
    playing = True
    while playing:
        active, passive = passive, active  # switch roles
        playing = not ask_player(active, lower_limit, upper_limit)
```